# How do I select all checkbox with a unique name?

Tags: .net, jquery

I am creating checkboxes with a loop.  I would like to uncheck all checkboxes that **START** with the name "NameCheckBox" with id "nameChk".  Therefore all the following will not be set to check.

```
<input id='nameChk1' name='NameCheckBox1' type='checkbox' />
<input id='nameChk2' name='NameCheckBox2' type='checkbox' />
<input id='nameChk4' name='NameCheckBox4' type='checkbox' />
```

and the following will not be affected

```
<input id='dateChk1' name='DateCheckBox1' type='checkbox' />
<input id='dateChk2' name='DateCheckBox2' type='checkbox' />
<input id='dateChk3' name='DateCheckBox3' type='checkbox' />
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You want to do this in the page behind code?

Comment: you work that in asp or silverlight or some other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [starts-with attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to target the elements you want..

```
$('input:checkbox[name^=NameCheckBox][id^=nameChk]').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: making this `input:checkbox` would increase performance, otherwise, the universal selector "*" is implied.

Comment: My code was set up input:[id^=nameChk] - Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good way of doing it. You're better off identifying these name fields with some kind of css class.

`<input id="foo" class="namecheck">`

then use `$(".namecheck").attr("checked", false);` to uncheck them when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:checkbox[name^=NameCheckBox]').removeAttr('checked');
```

You can do the same for id instead of name.
However, using a common class name is better and most likely faster.

Comment: should be `:checkbox` (*missing the `:`*)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `attr()` to get the name and/or id of the items...

http://jsfiddle.net/GzTpp/2/